# Inserting data into hsqldb using DAO pattern

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, hsqldb

Hi i am new to Java web development, im trying pass data into database through form, using data access object.

Heres the method for inserting data i´ve created so far :

```
public void addCustomer(String firstname, String lastName, String code)
{
    try
    {
        st = getConnection().createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate("insert into customer value(id ," + firstname + "," + lastName + "," + code+")");

    } catch(Exception e)
    {

        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {

        closeResources(); //method which closes connection, resultset and statements
    }

}
```

Now im calling this method in Servlet which looks like this :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(
            "<form action='/Add' method='post'>"
           +"Eesnimi:<input id='firstNameBox' name='firstName'/> "
           +"Perekonnanim:<input id='lastNameBox' name='lastName'/>"        
           +"Kood:<input id='codeBox' name='code'/>"    
           +"<input type='submit' value='Lisa'/>"   
           );
    String firstname = request.getParameter("firstName");
    String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
    String code = request.getParameter("code");
    CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
    dao.addCustomer(firstname, lastName, code);
}
```

Now im getting `SQLSyntaxErrorException : user lacks privilege or object not found: NULL`
Im pretty sure that the case is in the `addCustomer` method, but i couldnt find solution from google, perhaps anyone here can help me?

Answer (score 1):

The insert statement syntax seems to be wrong, since you got SQLSyntaxErrorException on:

```
st.executeUpdate("insert into customer value(
```

Try this:

```
st.executeUpdate("insert into customer values (
```

Also, remember that the order on  VALUES clause should be the same order that you created on customer table. Otherwhise, you have to use the complete INSERT syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Comment: thanks,but now im getting row and column count mismatch error. Does Sql syntax allow adding variable into statements?

Comment: Hum, I see in your SQL statement that "id" is not a value that comes from your java code. Is it auto increment field? If yes, I think you can omit from values clause.